# Index material in 2.8 (Cryptomatte)

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a lamp. Behind the glass is a source of light. I want to apply effects to the light source in the composer. Previously, this was done using a material index. In 2.8 this isn't possible, there is Cryptomatte. But the source of light is behind glass, so I can't pick it to get a number. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly how to do it, but you can try to reduce alpha transparency of your glass object and adjust your Alpha Threshold value on View Layer settings. Just after that you can use cryptomatte object to pick the light.
[image]